# Jquery easing animations lag on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, requestanimationframe

I've been developing a web app game for iOS and I've noticed a significant difference in performance on the iPhone verses the iPad. When the player starts a level there are up to 20 animations called at once using jQuery `.animate()` with jQuery UI easings. There's never any problem with lag or performance issues on any of the iPhones but, at least the iPad mini with retina, there seems to be a lot of lag issues.

I've read that `requestanimationframe` is supposed to be a better method but how can I use this and still maintain my jQuery UI easing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following post

[Velocity.js](http://css-tricks.com/improving-ui-animation-workflow-velocity-js/)

Velocity.js reimplements jQuery.animate().

A sample from the link posted above

[jQuery Syntax]

```
$div
 /* Fade an element in while sliding it into view. */
 .animate({ opacity: 1, top: "50%" })
 /* The values below are what we originally set the element to in our  stylesheet. Animate back to them. */ 
 .animate({ opacity: 0, top: "-25%" });
```

[Velocity.js]

```
$div
 .velocity({ opacity: 1, top: "50%" })
 .velocity("reverse");
```

More info can be found at the following link pointing to the main page of Velocity.js

[Velocity.js Main page](http://julian.com/research/velocity/)

You can download Velocity.js from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/julianshapiro/velocity/master/velocity.min.js)